# Bash script error: line 167: syntax error near unexpected token 'then'

Tags: bash, macos

I am getting an error in my bash script and I don't see anything wrong with it. Here is the code that is giving me the error.

```
if [ "$password" = "na" ]; then  
   log "Password not set"  
   usage  
   exit 1  
fi
```

Could anyone see anything wrong with this? It looks fine to me but I am also pretty new to bash in general.

EDIT: Here are the previous lines of code, maybe that will help.

```
if [ "$SITE" = "unknown" ]; then
    log "Site not set"
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$VERSION" = "na" ]; then
    log "Version not set"
    usage
    exit 1
fi

if [ "$password" = "na" ]; then  
   log "Password not set"  
   usage  
   exit 1  
fi
```

Comment: Maybe the error is in some previous line?

Comment: Probably carriage returns.

Comment: I'd guess this is a nested if/then, and we'd need to see the previous lines of code.

Comment: Check your file with `cat -A filename.sh` for special characters and then use `dos2unix filename.sh` to remove them.

Comment: Run your code through shellcheck.net to eliminate the obvious potential errors.

Comment: Run the script with -x to run it in debug mode.

Comment: Just added more code. Maybe that will help explain it!

Comment: @Cyrus It wouldn't let me do that cat command. I am on OS X if that makes a difference.

Comment: Okay, try `cat -v filename.sh`. Maybe there is option `-v` with OS X.

Comment: @Cyrus That worked. I'll see if that alleviates the issue.

Comment: check also the value of the variables (echo just before the corresponding if), in case they have any strange characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works without errors for me. I will guess that your file may contain 'hidden' characters (most likely a '\r' - carriage return - but could be something else).  Use to native Vi/Vim family of editors to avoid this; otherwise, check the settings in your text editor and set your 'line endings' to Unix/OSX. Try this:

```
tr -d '\r' /path/your_file.sh > /path/your_file.mod.sh  

bash -n /path/your_file.sh      ## should show error
bash -n /path/your_file.mod.sh  ## no errors
```

:)
Dale